# How to make bold appear less bold and the font lighter in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am transitioning from Google Sheets to LibreOffice because of privacy concerns and other reasons.

Now, I compare the design of a sheet in LibreOffice Cal with Google Sheets (same sheet opened):

**1. LibreOffice Calc:**

[image: LibreOffice Calc]

**2. Google Sheets:**

[image: Google Sheets]

Both are with font Arial and 100 % zoom. However, both look different from each other.

Reducing the zoom in LibreOffice Calc to 90 % helps a little, but still it seems chunky and bold text is still too bold.

Why does bold and the font in Google Sheets appear more clean and light than LibreOffice?

Can this be changed in the settings in LibreOffice Calc?

Is it just a zoom issue? Or some rendering settings?

**Update 1:**

I exported as XLSX, and LibreOffice opens the file with a font size of `11 pt` for the same cell. – Now I manually changed the cell to `10 pt` in LibreOffice Calc and now it looks similar to Google Sheets.

**Update 2:**

From the LibreOffice Calc settings > Tools > Options > Libre Office > View:

[image: LibreOffice Calc settings]

I disabled "Use Skia for all Rendering" and now the rendering of the table looks like this in LO Calc:

[image: LO Office calc without hardware acceleration]

Comment: What font size (in points) is set in both – 10 pt, 12 pt? "100% zoom" is meaningless if it's not specified 100% of what it is. What browser is displaying Google Sheets? What OS are both programs running on?

Comment: Unbelievable. You gave the right hint. The font size in Google Sheets is `10`. I exported as XLSX, and LibreOffice opens the file with a font size of `11 pt` for the same cell. (!) – Now I manually changed the cell to `10 pt` in LibreOffice Calc and now it looks very similar.

Comment: In other words: There is an issue with the export-import that changes the font size! ... I have checked other exported XLSX files, the same problem.

Comment: They're still going to look a little different even with the same size, I suspect, due to different text renderers (how they implement hinting, subpixel positioning, etc – the bottom screenshot looks like Chrome using Windows' standard ClearType, while LO might be using cross-platform HB/FT2).

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the new view. It is good enough now.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I disabled "Use Skia for all Rendering" and now the rendering of the table looks like the one in Google Sheets.